# Why are there 37 numbers on European roulette wheels?

Tags: 20th-century, 19th-century, 18th-century, early-modern, modern

A [European roulette](https://www.casinonewsdaily.com/roulette-guide/european-roulette/) wheel contains the numbers 0 to 36. Who decided to put 37 numbers on a wheel, and why did they choose this number?

Comment: [Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786) Does [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roulette#History) answer the question? Is there any reason to believe that this is in scope for history? that historical sources and methods will help to answer this question?

Comment: There are several different types of [roulette wheel](https://casino.partycasino.com/en/blog/roulette-wheel-numbers/). American wheels have 38 pockets (adding 00 to the house).

Comment: The answer is probably down to mathematics and greed. The original tables were broken up into 36 elements because that divides neatly into 360 degrees. Then someone thought that the house needed an extra advantage and added the 0 (and then the Americans thought that the house needed an extra, extra advantage and added 00)

Comment: @KillingTime It would seem to be the other way around if the information in Wikipedia is correct.

Comment: 37 is a prime number - could be a way break the symmetry that might favor some numbers over the others due to the table construction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The single 0 style roulette wheel was introduced in 1843 to compete against other casinos double 0 style roulette wheel that has existed at least since 1794.

Other versions had 70 ([Biribi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biribi)), some had less.

---

> [Roulette - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roulette#History):
>
> The game has been played in its present form since as early as 1796 in Paris. An early description of the roulette game in its current form is found in a French novel La Roulette, ou le Jour by Jaques Lablee, which describes a roulette wheel in the Palais Royal in Paris in 1796. The description included the house pockets, "There are exactly two slots reserved for the bank, whence it derives its sole mathematical advantage." It then goes on to describe the layout with, "...two betting spaces **containing the bank's two numbers, zero and double zero**". The book was published in 1801. An even earlier reference to a game of this name was published in regulations for New France (Québec) in 1758, which banned the games of "dice, hoca, faro, and roulette".
>
> The roulette wheels used in the casinos of Paris in the late 1790s had red for the single zero and black for the double zero. To avoid confusion, the color green was selected for the zeros in roulette wheels starting in the 1800s.
>
> In 1843, in the German spa casino town of Bad Homburg, fellow Frenchmen François and Louis Blanc **introduced the single 0 style roulette** wheel in order to compete against other casinos offering the traditional wheel with single and double zero house pockets.

Comment: That explains why 37 instead of 36 or 38. But why was 36 chosen initially?

Comment: @Riemann I doubt that that can be reliably determined.

Answer (score 2):

*Perhaps a bit of **historical context** might help **clarify** the mystery, by comparing its numerical choice, to that of **other games of chance** ?*

---

Though currently revered as constituting primarily a game of intellect, [chess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_chess#Origin) has its own [dice–based version](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaturaji), played, of course, with **32** pieces, revolving around the **four** main divisions of ancient Indian military; namely, infantry (pawns), cavalry (knights), war elephants (bishops), and chariots (rooks).

A simple glimpse at a [list of card games by number of cards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_card_games_by_number_of_cards) reveals those played with of 52, **32,** and **36** cards as the most numerous. Needless to say, most such decks consist of **four** suits, oftentimes colored **red** and **black.**

A [list of traditional card and tile packs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_traditional_card_and_tile_packs) informs us that :

> **32**-card packs [...] are **very common in Europe.**
>
> **36**-card packs [...are] in use in western Switzerland [...] and [are] **quite common in Russia**
>
> **40**-card packs are **found mostly in Latin countries** where they compete against local Italian or Spanish suited decks.
>
> ---
>
> Full **German**-suited packs [...] contain **36** cards, organized into the **four** German suits
>
> without the [four] sixes, [it is] used for **many** Central European games
>
> The [...] **frequently** encountered **Swiss**-suited [...] [Jass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jass) pack [...] contains **36** cards
>
> ---
>
> The **standard Spanish**-suited pack consists of **40** cards
>
> the **standard Italian**-suited pack consists of **40** cards

Though the [standard 52-card deck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_52-card_deck) is quite popular nowadays,

> there are **many** countries or regions where the traditional pack size is only **36** (Russia, Bavaria) or **32** (north and central Germany, Austria)
>
> **40**- or 48-card Italian-suited packs are **common in Italy**
>
> **40**- and 48-card **Spanish**-suited packs on the Iberian peninsula
>
> **36**-card **German**-suited packs are **very common** in Bavaria and Austria.

As far as [French-suited playing cards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French-suited_playing_cards) are concerned,

> The **most common** deck sold in **France** is the **32**-card deck
>
> The **French-Swiss** pattern [...] comes only in decks of **36**
>
> **Belgian** packs come in either **32** or 52 cards
>
> ---
>
> The **Dutch** pattern [...] come[s] in decks of **32** [...] or 52 cards.
>
> The **North-German** pattern [...is] **usually** in decks of **32** cards
>
> ---
>
> **Genoese** type cards [...] come in **36** [...], **40** [...] or 52-card packs.
>
> The **Lombard** or **Milanese** pattern come[s] in **40**-card decks
>
> ---
>
> The **Russian** pattern [...] usually contains 52 or **36** cards
>
> [It] can be found in **many** countries that were once part of the Russian Empire or Soviet Union.

The *Wikipedia* article also contains a [picture](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0a/Deck_of_cards_used_in_the_game_piquet.jpg) of a

> **Standard 32**-card deck of the **Paris** pattern.

For [Swiss-suited playing cards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swiss-suited_playing_cards),

> The **most common** deck has **36** cards.

[German-suited playing cards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German-suited_playing_cards)

> are a **very common** style [...] used in **many** parts of Central Europe characterized by **32**- or **36**-card packs
>
> The **typical northern German** pack has **32** cards
>
> **Southern** patterns have **36** cards
>
> **Northern** patterns [...] were originally produced with **36** cards but this was reduced to **32** cards
>
> **Most** [southern] games require only **32** cards
>
> The **Württemberg** pattern [...] used to be produced in **36** card packs
>
> ---
>
> The [...] Double **German** [...] pattern is **popular** throughout the former **Austro-Hungarian Empire.**
>
> [It] come[s] in packs of **32, 33** [...], or **36** cards.
>
> In **Hungary** and other **eastern European** countries they [...] come in **32**-card packs.
>
> ---
>
> In **South Tyrol, 40**-card, **German**-suited packs are still produced so that **Italian** games can be played with them.
>
> **German** speaking **South Tyroleans** [...] play **Italian** card games that require **40** cards

Indeed,

> The *Salisburghesi* deck originally consisted of **33** cards, being the **32** cards used for **Tyrolean** games [...] plus [...] a wild card
>
> This has since been increased to **40** cards as per **most** other [**Italian** decks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Italian_playing_cards)

Speaking of which,

> **40**-card stripped decks [...] are the **most common** format found in **Italy** today.
>
> This is the result of **popular** 16th and 17th century games
>
> **Trentine** cards are sold in either packs of **40** or 52.
>
> The **Bergamasche** pattern comes in decks of **40** cards only.
>
> The **Trevisane** deck [...] comes in sets of **40** or 52.
>
> the **Triestine** pack [...] was created in the mid-19th century [...] now only **40** card decks are sold.
>
> the **40** card Primiera **Bolognese** set [...is] used for **standard** games
>
> **Fiorentine** cards come in packs of **40**
>
> the **Sardinian** deck only contains the **standard Italian** set of **40**

When it comes to [Spanish-suited playing cards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish-suited_playing_cards),

> a deck is **usually** made up of **40** or 48 cards
>
> Stripped decks have **40** cards
>
> The **Castilian** pattern is the **most widespread** pattern in **Spain.**
>
> [It] come[s] in packs of **40** or 50 cards.
>
> The **Mexican** pattern [...] come[s] in decks of **40** cards
>
> the **Old Catalan** pattern [...is] found in decks of **40** or 48 cards.
>
> The **Cádiz** pattern [...is] found in decks of **40** or **50** cards.
>
> The **Modern Spanish Catalan** pattern is the **second most widespread** pattern in **Spain** and is **very common** in **Hispanic America.**
>
> [It] come[s] in decks of **40** or 50 cards.
>
> The **Parisian Spanish** [...] pattern [...is] sold in decks of **40** or 50 cards.
>
> The **Piacentine** pattern [...] come[s] in **40**-card decks.

[In conclusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stripped_deck),

> The **Spanish, Portuguese, Italians,** and **Latin Americans** use mostly **40**-card decks.

Furthermore,

> The **most popular** card game in 16th-century **Europe** was [Piquet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piquet), played with a **36**-card deck
>
> Around 1700, it [...] create[d] the **32**-card deck, which is now the **most popular** format in **France.**
>
> **32** and **36**-card decks are the **most widespread** in countries that were once part of the **Holy Roman** (the Low Countries, Germany, and Switzerland), **Austro-Hungarian,** and **Russian empires.**

The encyclopedic article also includes a [picture](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e7/Skatblatt_Turnierbild.jpg) of

> A **32**-card Piquet deck.

[Last, but not least](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Card_game),

> **Germanic, Spanish** and **Italian** Tarot variants [...] creat[e] a deck with as few as **32** cards.

Answer (score 2):

36 is a [Highly Composite Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highly_composite_number):

> A highly composite number is a positive integer with more divisors than any smaller positive integer has.

36 can be divided by 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 9, 12, and 18. This allows for many ways to bet on groups of numbers with equal chances.

Remember that you can put chips not only on **one** number (*plein*), but on the line between **two** numbers (*cheval*), on the outside line of a row of **three** numbers (*transversale plein*), the crossing of lines between **four** numbers (*carré*), on the T of a line dividing two rows of numbers with the outside line (**six** numbers, *traversale simple*), on the **twelve** numbers 1-12, 13-24, 25-36 (*douzaines*) or in a column (*colonnes*), and various variants of betting on half the numbers (**eighteen** -- *pair* / *impair*, *passe* / *manque*, *rouge* / *noir*). This is possible only because 36 divides evenly into each of those (as well as nine, which is AFAIK not used for betting though).

---

Similar reasoning (highly composite numbers) is why dice have 6 sides, many customary units come in twelves, the day has 24 hours, an hour has 60 minutes or the compass has 360 degrees: Easy to divide any which way without having to deal with remainders.